# Incremental Correctness Recursive Algorithm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

The pseudocode for incrementing natural numbers using a recursive algorithm is like this (example from the Algorithm Design Manual by Steven S. Skiena):

```
Increment(y)
 if y = 0 then return(1) else
  if (y mod 2) = 1 then
      return(2 * Increment(y/2))
  else return(y + 1)
```

I implemented it with JavaScript here: https://repl.it/@danielmai/IncrementalNaturalNumbers

```
function increment(y) {
  if(y == 0) return 1
  if(y % 2 == 1) {
    return 2 * increment(y / 2)
  }
  else return y + 1
}
```

It doesn't work for odd numbers. I found out that JavaScript rounds up numbers with 0.5 or higher, so if `y` is odd, it will increment twice, i.e `5 -> 7`.

I can use `Math.floor(y/2)` to make it round down, but I assume this function should work regardless of rounding up or down. So my question is, is there a way to correct this recursive function in JS without using `Math.floor`?

Comment: Javascript has no integer division, so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with javascript rounding numbers up with 0.5 or higher.

Your increment function is asuming x / 2 will return an integer, but in javascript this will give a decimal number when odd. So when doing increment(3), you are recursively calling increment(1.5). As 1.5 % 2 = 1.5, its not == 1 so it ends up returning 2.5. So in the end, you end up returning 2.5 * 2 = 5.

This funcion would indeed work on c++ where if you are working with integers, division will trim trailing decimals. However, in javascript addition +, subtraction -, multiplication *, division /, power **, and modulo % all treat numbers in JavaScript as a double. Only binary operators treat numbers in JavaScript as a signed 32 bit integer.

Comment: I see. JavaScript is different than other languages that it treats integers as double values, so integer division can be a whole number or a fraction. So there's nothing wrong with the algorithm, just its implementation with JavaScript needs a little tweak.  I think using `Math.floor()` would be fine in this case, performance-wise? Thank you. Marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have integer division, so you can't just do 5/2 and expect it to give you 2.

If you're looking for an alternative to `Math.floor`, [this website](https://jsperf.com/math-floor-alternatives) has you covered. It has all of the alternatives you could ever want, and can check which will be the fastest on your browser.